# Rails undefined path method in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, html-table

I am trying to make the page generate a table of lessons, where each cell is a text field, where you can edit the value and save it by pressing a button. The button should run the update action, updating the attributes.

```
<% @group.lessons.each do |lesson| %>

        <% form_for lesson do |f| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= f.text_field :time %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :day %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :subject %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :teacher %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :room %></td>
                <td><%= f.submit 'Update'%></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Delete', [lesson.group, lesson], method: :delete%></td>
            </tr>
        <%end%>
    <%end%>
```

Group has_many :lessons, lesson belongs_to :group (just to make it clear).

I get this error on line 14:

> undefined method `lesson_path' for #<#:0x30831d8>

line 14:

```
<% form_for lesson do |f| %>
```

Extract from routes.rb as requested:

```
resources :groups do
    resources :lessons
end
root :to => 'groups#index'
```

How do I achieve what I need?

Comment: You need to show us your routes file as well. :)

Comment: run `rake routes` and paste output here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have:

```
<%= form_for [@group, lesson] do |f| %>
```

in your view. This is necessary since `lessons` are nested resources inside `groups` resources, so you need to pass `group_id` to the link if you want it to route to `LessonsController`.